# Saving all iterations from a for loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am trying to run a for loop that allows me to get a list of names that correspond to intersections between data further in the loop.

Nevertheless when I try to safe the output of the "names" on an empty list I only get the results of the last iteration.

```
for(i in 1:length(FamiliasCOGSEG)){
        FCStemp=FamiliasCOGSEG[-i]

        nombres.cruces<-list()
        listacruces<-list()     

        for (j in 1:length(FCStemp)){
            nombres.cruces[j]<-(paste(nombresfamiliasagruadas[i],"con",nombresfamiliasagruadas[j]))
}
}
```

Here is my code, what I need is that "nombres.cruces" saves all the results and not just the last iteration so I can use the list further on the loop.

The output of *nombres.cruces* is a list of 38 objects looking like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "fam3 con Ind1"
.
.
.

[[37]]
[1] "fam3 con fam22"
```

Comment: Define your lists outside of the loop. Each loop, you create an empty list, fill it and then overwrite it in the following loop. I.e before your first `for` statement, create your lists, then run your loops.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]